# Why does this for loop don't work? (CS0162)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a Dice Game. Why stands there, (where i commentated) "Unreachable Code detected / CS0162.) The result i'm hoping for that for loop is: To set the "Spielerpunkt" on 1 and letting the "Gegnerpunkt" on 0 (At least for that loop) No full code spoilers please. Just for that situation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drücke eine Taste um den Würfel zu rollen.");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
                Random You = new Random();
                var yourChoice = You.Next(0, 5);
                Console.WriteLine("\nDu hast eine {0} gewürfelt", yourChoice);
                Console.WriteLine(". . .");

                Random Enemy = new Random();
                var enemyChoice = Enemy.Next(0, 5);
                Console.WriteLine("Gegnerische AI hat eine {0} gewürfelt", enemyChoice);

                if (yourChoice > enemyChoice)
                {
                    for (int SpielerPunkt = 0, GegnerPunkt = 0; yourChoice > enemyChoice; SpielerPunkt++) // HERE IS THE PROBLEM (CS0162)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Das Ergebnis ist jetzt - Spieler : " + SpielerPunkt + " Gegner : " + GegnerPunkt);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your stepper function doesn't affect the check condition that's why the compiler whining. `yourChoice > enemyChoice` will always remain the same. And you already check that it is true. It's basically a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: Also: You return from the loop unconditionally!

Comment: @Eldar do you have a solution for that problem?

Comment: As far as I understand from your implementation you may not need a loop at all. Also, I didn't quite get what do variables named `SpielerPunkt` and `SpielerPunkt` do.

Comment: The unreachable code is all the code that would execute after your unconditional `return` statement (in particular, the `SpielerPunkt++` and the `i++`). You should have only one `Random` instance and you should construct it outside the loop (look at about a quarter of all questions about Random for information)

Comment: @Eldar Its basically means PlayerPoint & EnemiePoint. I want if you win the dice, the console writes the score

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `return` statement at the end of the for loop, loop will iterate only one time and returns current method. But when you remove the `return` statement loop will never end. Also score will never save because variables is declared inside loop and this will create new variables every new iteration.
I guess thats the fix what you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drücke eine Taste um den Würfel zu rollen.");
        int SpielerPunkt = 0, GegnerPunkt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            Random You = new Random();
            var yourChoice = You.Next(0, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("\nDu hast eine {0} gewürfelt", yourChoice);
            Console.WriteLine(". . .");

            Random Enemy = new Random();
            var enemyChoice = Enemy.Next(0, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("Gegnerische AI hat eine {0} gewürfelt", enemyChoice);

            if (yourChoice > enemyChoice) SpielerPunkt++;
            else if (enemyChoice > yourChoice) GegnerPunkt++;

            Console.WriteLine("Das Ergebnis ist jetzt - Spieler : " + SpielerPunkt + " Gegner : " + GegnerPunkt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And, there should be only one instance of `Random` and it should be constructed outside the loop